# How do I prefix class names wih a custom string?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, redis

In order to implement some kind of namespace, I need to prefix the keys of a Redis JPA repository with a static string within a whole Spring application.

I read about the `spring.cache.redis.key-prefix` configuration option but it seems to be applicable to caches only.

How do I get the same behavior for JPA repositories?

Answer (score 2):

In your `@EnableRedisReposiories` you can do:

```
@EnableRedisRepositories(keyspaceConfiguration = MyCustomKeyspaceConfiguration.class)
```

Then in the App config add a `RedisMappingContext` bean and the customer keyspace configuration class:

```
@Bean
public RedisMappingContext keyValueMappingContext() {
  return new RedisMappingContext(
    new MappingConfiguration(new IndexConfiguration(), new MyCustomKeyspaceConfiguration()));
}

public static class MyCustomKeyspaceConfiguration extends KeyspaceConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected Iterable<KeyspaceSettings> initialConfiguration() {
    List<KeyspaceSetting> settings = new ArrayList<KeyspaceSetting>();
    settings.add(new KeyspaceSetting(Foo.class, "my-prefix" + Foo.class.getName()));
    return settings;
  }
}
```

In the case above we're saying that for the class `Foo` prefix the keys with `"my-prefix"`. `KeyspaceConfiguration` allows for the programmatic setup of keyspaces and time to live options for certain types.